# WAMP virtual hosting displaying same website

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

On my WAMP local Host I am running two different social engine websites, in my hosts file I added two lines:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.com

127.0.0.1 site2.com
```

in my apache.conf file I have added this code for virtual hosting

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /wamp/www/se3
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    ErrorLog logs/site1-error_log
    CustomLog logs/site1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /wamp/www/site2
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias site2.com
    ErrorLog logs/site2-error_log
    CustomLog logs/site2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the problem which I am facing is, when on browser when I type `site1.com` it loads site1 correctly,
but when I type `site2.com` it loads site1.

I can't find out the actual problem behind this.

Can any one help me out?

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got name based virtual hosting enabled with a NameVirtualHost directive somewhere?

eg: `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1`

Comment: in httpd.conf file their is no where written such line, should I add it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise Apache will default to IP based virtual hosting where each virtual host will need to be on a separate IP address.